# creating indexes on a simpe table

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and creating a simple telephone book the table contains `first_name`, `last_name` and `phone_number` fields

I want to search for `first_name` or `last_name`

I performance should be good if we have over few millions data sets. which indexes do I need or what should i take care of?

Comment: Put one on `first_name`, if you want to search by first name only. Analog for last name. If you also want to search by first and last name together (which presumably is the case in any "real world" phone books) put one on the combination of `first_name` and `last_name`.

Comment: Include a unique ID field for each person and use it as a primary key. This way each person has a unique identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want three indexes, presumably on:

```
(first_name)
(last_name, first_name)
(phone_number)
```

The second allows you to search by both first and last names.